# Karate : check if an element is located below an other

Tags: select, parent-child, karate

I have this html :

```
<div>
  <div>
    <select attribute = "first select"> 
      <option1></option>
      <option1></option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div>
<div>
  <div>
    <select attribute = "second select"> 
      <option1></option>
      <option1></option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div>
```

Can I check if the "second select" is below "first select" in karate?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <select class="first select"> 
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <select class="second select"> 
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then this will work:

```
* def data = scriptAll('select', "_.getAttribute('class')")
* print 'data:', data
* def firstIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.includes('first'))
* def secondIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.includes('second'))
* print 'firstIndex:', firstIndex, 'secondIndex:', secondIndex 
* assert firstIndex < secondIndex
```

Personally I don't like these kinds of tests. But you get the point, if you convert HTML into JSON, then you can do some analysis on it.